# Bootstrap 4 navbar layout works using CDN, breaks using downloaded code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Navbars load collapsed and improperly formatted using downloaded Bootstrap 4 Alpha code, but appear fine using the Bootstrap 4 Alpha CDN. Using the downloaded code is necessary for this project.

Navbar appearance using downloaded Bootstrap 4 Alpha code: 
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEUnS.png)

Navbar appearance using Bootstrap 4 Alpha CDN (the look I want): [View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJwQn.png)

This is my HTML, it doesn't change:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Meet the Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

No idea what's wrong or how to fix this. Anyone familiar with this issue? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have downloaded the Alpha version, but the CDN is the beta version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 to beta](https://medium.com/wdstack/upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-beta-ca582f15ee32), `navbar-toggleable-*` changed to `navbar-expand-*`, so if you're using `navbar-expand-*` with alpha it wouldn't work.

If you want it to work in **alpha 6**, it would be:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">..</nav>`

If you want it to work in **beta**, it would be:

`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">..</nav>`