# Bootstrap v4.0.0 not working Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-4

**Hello.**

I started to make a site in **Wordpress** when I found out that the basic bootstrap components didn't work.

- Yes, they are linked good. (No errors in my developer tools)
- Yes, the files are not bootstrap 3, I use the current updated version 4.0.0.
- Yes, everything else works just fine.
- No, I wasn't able to find my question anywhere on the internet. (Blind?)

**My index.php code:**

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

**My footer.php code:**

```html
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script link="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**My header.php code:**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
    <?= get_the_title(); ?>
</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
</head>
```

[**My result IMAGE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RYfl.png)

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Read the [beta docs](http://getbootstrap.com). `navbar-toggleable-*` is now `navbar-expand-*` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907022/bootstrap-v4-navbar-bug/45907207

Answer (score 1):

You could use [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) along with [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

## Usage :

```
function add_boostrap_assets() {
  wp_enqueue_style("boostrap", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ."assets/css/bootstrap.css");
  wp_enqueue_script("boostrap", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ."assets/js/boostrap.js", false);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_boostrap_assets' );
```

**PS :** knowing that boostrap need jQuery to work properly, I don't see jQuery anywhere.